# Variable Undefined in Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function updateServerList() {
    var i;

    for (i=0; i < servers.length; i++) {
     var server = servers[i];
     var ip = server['serverIp']


     var html = constructServer(i);
     var divId = '#server' + ip.replace(new RegExp("\\.", "mg"), "-");
     var visible = $(divId).find(".server_body").is(":visible");
     var div = $(divId);
     div.html(html);

     // Set div class.
     var prevState = div.attr('class').substring(7)
     if (prevState != server['state']) {

         if (server['state'] == 'ok') {
         console.debug(server);
         div.slideUp('fast', function(server) {
             $(this).removeClass();
             $(this).addClass('server_ok');
             var id = ipToId[server['serverIp']];
             console.debug(id);
             if (id == 0) {
             adjacentIp = servers[1]['serverIp'];
             adjacentDivId = '#server' + adjacentIp.replace(new RegExp('\\.', 'g'), '-');
             $(adjacentDivId).before(this);
             }
        }).delay(1000);
        div.slideDown();
        }
    }
}
```

`console.debug` shows `server` as being defined, but inside the anonymous function, `server` is not defined. What am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because `server` is an argument to the function, its masking the value of the `server` at the higher level.  You need to either pass server to the function, or remove the function argument.  I would do the latter, as `slideUp` doesn't give you a way to pass arguments.  You could do it but its needlessly complicated; it would look something like the following

```
div.slideUp('fast', (function(server) { 
   return function(){ 
      // your stuff here, server is now 'closed in', i.e. in a closure
   }
})(server)); // <-- this server is the current value in the loop
```

what you are doing here is invoking a new function right away, passing in the argument server, and returning a new function that receives that value.

Comment: How do I pass it to the function?

Comment: @AlexBliskovsky: you don't need to. You can just access it when you have declared it like that.

Comment: Just remove the argument `server` from the inner function; I don't believe those animation callbacks pass an argument, anyways.

Comment: The callback is inside a loop and by the time it is called, the value of `server` seems to have changed. I need the value of `server` at a specific point in time.

Comment: @AlexBliskovsky: if that's the case you should really make sure you post all relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var server = servers[i];

var prevState = div.attr('class').substring(7);

if (prevState != server['state']) {

   if (server['state'] == 'ok') {
      console.debug(server);
      div.slideUp('fast', function() {
            ...
         var id = ipToId[server['serverIp']];
     }
}
```

Inside your anonymous function, "server" is still within the function scope.  No need to pass it in as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

### The Quick Fix

```
// ...

div.slideUp('fast', function() { // `server` argument removed
    // ...
});
```

### The Explanation

There is no need to pass `server` to the function. The anonymous function "closes" over the `server` variable.

---

This is merely a function *declaration*:

```
function (server) {...}
```

You aren't passing anything to the function yet, as it isn't being *invoked* yet! The `(server)` bit 
in a function declaration simply lets you name the arguments to your function. Only when you *invoke* the function can you *pass* arguments:

```
var name = "Jill";
var showName = function (name) {
    alert(name);
};

showName("Jack"); // alert box shows "Jack"
showName(); // alert box shows "undefined"
```

So, when you declare that the name of the first argument to your anonymous function is `server`, there is a name conflict which prevents the original from being accessible; the `server` in your anonymous function is whatever `slideUp` passes as the first argument, which, [according to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/), is *nothing*, so `server` is now `undefined`.

If this is confusing (and I suspect it is), I would suggest reading about javascript closures. [Here's a good place to get started](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml).

---

**Fun fact**: you can actually access arguments, in order, without having any explicit names, by using Javascript's built in `arguments` array object inside a function:

```
var sum = function () {
    var i, total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        total = total + arguments[i];
    }
    return total ;
};

alert(sum(1,2,3)); // Displays "6"
alert(sum(1,2,3,4)); // Displays "10"
alert(sum(1,0,2,3)); // Displays "6"
alert(sum()); // Displays "0"
```